# re.split unless following character an integer in Python

Tags: python, regex

In the following example, a string is converted into a list via Python's re.split(), using a single whitespace as delimiter. Splits must not occur if the following character of a split were an integer. My attempted code performs an additional, incorrect split for the first character of all elements > 1. 


Which regular expression would generate the desired output?


**Conceptual Input:**

```
inString = "key=string key=integer key=(float float float) key=float"
```

**Desired Output:**

```
outList = ['key=string', 'key=integer', 'key=(float float float)', 'key=float']
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
outList = re.split("\s([^0-9].*?)", inString)
```

**Output of Attempted Code:**

```
['key=abcde', 'k', 'ey=12345', 'k', 'ey=(0.1234 1.2345 2.3456)', 'k', 'ey=0.1234']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the below code which uses negative lookahead,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "key=abc key=123 key=(0.1234 1.2345 2.3456) key=0.1234"
>>> m = re.split(r' (?!\d)', s)
>>> m
['key=abc', 'key=123', 'key=(0.1234 1.2345 2.3456)', 'key=0.1234']
```

And also you could try the below code, if you don't want to split the input string according to the spaces which are present inside `()`,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "key=abc key=123 key=(0.1234 1.2345 2.3456 foo bar) key=0.1234 key=123 key=(foo bar)"
>>> m = re.split(r' (?=[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)|[^()]*$))', s)
>>> m
['key=abc', 'key=123', 'key=(0.1234 1.2345 2.3456 foo bar)', 'key=0.1234', 'key=123', 'key=(foo bar)']
```

Comment: or `m = re.split(r'\s+(?!\d)', s)`

Comment: A short and succinct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can split on the regex: `(?=key)`:

```
inString = "key=string key=integer key=(float float float) key=float"
outList = re.split(" (?=key)", inString)
print outList # ['key=string', 'key=integer', 'key=(float float float)', 'key=float']
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

> Split string by the occurrences of pattern. If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list